# Gamecenter setting authenticate handler crashes

Tags: ios, swift3, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer(player: GKLocalPlayer) {
        player.authenticateHandler =
            ({ (viewController : UIViewController!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
                if viewController != nil {
                    self.present(viewController, animated:true, completion: nil)
                } else {

                }
                } as! (UIViewController?, Error?) -> Void)

    }
```

this freezes on  that last line -- as! (UIViewController?, Error?) -> Void)

with nothing in the stack trace beyond that.. just freezes execution. What's happening here?

How do I set the authenticate handler?

mouseover of the freeze: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)

Answer (score 3):

It is because you declared the wrong handler and attempted to fix it by force-casting it to `as! (UIViewController?, Error?) -> Void` which obviously will fail, as these types are not the same.

That's how it should look like:

```
player.authenticateHandler =
        ({ (viewController : UIViewController?, error : Error?) -> Void in
            if let vc = viewController {
                self.present(vc, animated:true, completion: nil)
            } else {

            }
        })
```

Make sure you do not trust Xcode too much and double check types yourself.